# Can c# understand this kind of pathing for pointing a file?

Tags: c#, path

`..\..\..\ConnectionInterface\ConnectionInterface.vbproj`

I mean the "..\"

Because I am reading up a .sln file as a text file to get all the projects in that solution and the problem is this projects inside where in different directories or level.

Here is an example

`..\..\..\ConnectionInterface\ConnectionInterface.vbproj`
`..\States\Components\States.vbproj`

any ideas how to get the actual paths of these projects?

Comment: Are you using an @ at the start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Path.Combine`, but you'll need to know where it's relative to. Basically find the directory that contains the original .sln file (e.g. using `Path.GetDirectoryName` and `Path.GetFullPath`) and then use `Path.Combine` to combine the original directory with the relative file.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        string originalFile = "Test.cs";
        string relative = @"..\Documents\Foo";

        string originalAbsoluteFile = Path.GetFullPath(originalFile);        
        string originalDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalAbsoluteFile);
        string combined = Path.Combine(originalDirectory, relative);
        string combinedAbsolute = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
        Console.WriteLine(combinedAbsolute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\ConnectionInterface\ConnectionInterface.vbproj");
```

This is relative to the current working directory, therefore if the relative reference is not based on the current working directory you will need to define that first.

Comment: If you change this to Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\ConnectionInterface\ConnectionInterface.vbproj"); then I think we agree ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting the idea

Comment: This will only work if the file was loaded from the current directory. Otherwise you need to specify which directory it's meant to be relative to.

Comment: It will only work if Environment.CurrentDirectory is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear, but if you mean does C# understand: C:\SomeDir\InnerDir1\ ..\InnerDir2 to resolve to C:\SomeDir\InnerDir2, then yes, it will work. Just append directory the solution file is in with the relative path, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, this could be another alternative